# How to display the name in popover?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here i am going to pass the store ids as 1 and 0.Here store_id='1' is bengaluru and store_id='0' as hyderabad..

here is my html code:

**`home.ts`**

```
presentPopover(myEvent) {
  let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(Popoverpage);
  popover.present({
    ev: myEvent
  });
}
```

**`home.html`**

```
<ion-header>

  <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)" >
    Choose City
    <ion-label>{{cityname}}</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" item-right></ion-icon>
  </button>

</ion-header>
```

Here if i am going to click "bengaluru" means it has to display that name in my popover and same as "hyderabad".

**`popoverpage.ts`**

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <ion-list>
          <button ion-item (click)="store()">Bengaluru</button>
          <button ion-item (click)="fun()">Hyderabad</button>
        </ion-list>
      `
})

export class Popoverpage{
    store_id
    cityname


    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,
                public navCtrl: NavController,
                public rest: Rest,
                public logger: Logger) {
    }

    store() {
        let  storeObj={
            store_id: '1'
        }

        this.logger.debug("checking the  " +JSON.stringify(storeObj));

        this.rest.post('/store',storeObj)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.logger.debug("checking the data "+JSON.stringify(result));
                if(result.status == '1'){
                    this.logger.info("success callback");
                    this.cityname="Bengaluru";

                    //this.navCtrl.pop();
                    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();

                }
                else{
                    this.logger.info("error callback");
                    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
                }
            })

    }

    fun() {
        let  storeObj={
            store_id: '0'
        }

        this.logger.debug("checking the  " +JSON.stringify(storeObj));

        this.rest.post('/store',storeObj)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.logger.debug("checking the data "+JSON.stringify(result));
                if(result.status == '1'){
                    this.logger.debug("success callback");
                    this.cityname="Hyderabad";
                    //this.navCtrl.pop();
                    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
                }
                else{
                    this.logger.debug("error callback");
                    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
                }
            })

    }

}
```

if any body knows please reply to this..

Comment: what was an issue ?

Comment: the issue is when i click choose city it showing a drop down right in that drop down if i click bengaluru or hyderabad it has to display that name

Comment: in popover means choose city is there like that it has to display

Comment: is it necessary to use popover you can use simple page and pass value by `NavParams`

Comment: if u have demo can u please send me the link or u can edit my code

Comment: please because i am new to ionic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you named the button click methods "store" and "fun", but keep in mind that you can always pass a string to your click handler method. Maybe something like this:

```
<button ion-item (click)="clicked('bangaluru')">Bengaluru</button>
<button ion-item (click)="clicked('hyderabad')">Hyderabad</button>

clicked (e) {
  console.log('clicked ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  this.currentCity = e; 
}
```

Here is a [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FXNv7mT1C9id1KlY3I3U?p=preview).